# Interupt a javascript redirect with a delay

Tags: javascript, redirect, delay

Im currently using a simple javascript redirect (called on load) with a delay to automatically redirect users from older articles to newer ones in a corporate wiki. However, Id like users to be able to stop the autoredirect so they can access the older data if needed.

How could I modify this code to achieve that?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var h = setTimeout("iiredirect()", 2000);
function iiredirect() { window.location = "that new location"; }
</script>
```

Comment: Please, please, please change `"iiredirect()"` to `iiredirect`.

Comment: @PeterOlson: Why? Either seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/simtali/P2ehw/

Comment: @Daniel They both will work, but passing a string parameter to `setTimeout` or `setInterval` does an eval of the code in the string, which is unnecessary when you can pass a function in directly.

Comment: Ah, I missed the string vs function bit and thought you were referring to function reference vs call.

Comment: @Daniel Passing a function call will immediately call the function. It passes whatever the function returns to `setTimeout`. If you used `setInterval` and passed a function call, you would notice that the function only runs once, and if you increased the delay in `setTimeout` passing in a function call you would notice that there is no delay.

Comment: Ah, that explains why my example seems to work properly (but doesn't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `button` is a reference to your *cancel redirection* button.

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    window.location = "that new location";
}, 2000);

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

clearTimeout(h) should do it. That will cancel the running timeout.